# GraphQL Prisma copy rows from template tables to other

Tags: postgresql, graphql, prisma-graphql

I have PostgreSQL DB behind a Prisma 1.34 and Graphql-yoga. 
There few linked tables(Prisma types/entities) that represent templates. These templates model hierarchical structure with parents and children that can be used in the creation of the actual entities that then user going to work with (edit these types, change text, description and properties).

The thing I need to do is to copy these templates into the different tables.
I was thinking to do it through the mutation. Just can wrap my head around the correct or right way of doing it. I can get the id of a parent entity from the user and then either query it from DB with all nested entities and then create it and all nested one. Is it the right way of doing it? or Prisma has something built-in or are the different solution (best practice) to do such things in Grapql setting?